# Return file as a download in Django Python

Tags: python, django, file, pdf

I have made a site using Django and I have made a function that returns an autogenerated pdf from database data.

To make the PDF I use pyFPDF.

```
pdfreport = FPDF()
#Code for the PDF here

pdfreport.output(name='mypdf.pdf')
```

With this code everything works well, the PDF is correctly generated.
But in order to return the file as an HTTP Response, I save the file with  `dest='S'` and make the response.

```
pdf = pdfreport.output(dest='S')
response = = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="mypdf.pdf"'
return(response)
```

Using this, the response is correct and I got the file to save, the browser load the file as a pdf, but the pdf is blank. And I don't know why this happen.

I have tried saving the file, open the file with `open()` and attach its content, but I still got the same result, a blank pdf.

```
pdfreport.output(name=pdfname)
pdf = open(pdfname, 'r')
response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="mypdf.pdf"'
return(response)
```

Anyone that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the file that saves FPDF and the one that is sent by HTTP Response, I realize that there is an encoding error so I found this in the official documentation.

> NOTICE: In Python 2 strings were raw data but in Python 3 strings are now unicode by default. If you are using Python 3.x you have to use `pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1')` in order to get the output, if you don't do so the generated PDF will be invalid and depending on the viewer either not open at all or show up as some blank pages.

And I tried it encoding as `latin-1` and it finally works.